# Can't mount internal hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I'm having some trouble with my internal hard drive and was hoping you smart people could help me. So, here's all that has happened so far:

Thursday of last week, my Acer Win 7 (updated to Win 10) computer began an update. I thought it was business as usual, but I was wrong. First, it was stuck on a page that just said "restarting", after applying the update. I waited quite a while, but nothing happened. The only thing I thought I could do was a hard shutdown (since it was going to restart anyway). It started to boot like normal (showed the Acer logo and blinking cursor for a second), but then it went to a black screen. I waited hours and nothing happened.

So, the first thing I decided to do was make a Win 10 iso bootable USB drive. After an hour of looking at the Windows logo, with its swirling loading symbol, a menu finally came up! I've tried a few different things (restore, reset, etc), but I got errors on all of them. Each time I selected an option on the Windows 10 menu, it took a good 30-45 minutes for it to go to a different page (system restore, image, etc).

Since this didn't seem to be working, I decided I'd use my trusty Ubuntu Live USB that I made; I've owned my PC quite a while and I've had to do this one other time. I knew it'd be a simple procedure: get my data off the hard drive and do a clean Win 10 reset, but I was wrong. When I clicked my ACER hard drive on the menu, I received this error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/ubuntu/ACER: Command-line `mount    -t       
"ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/sda3"     
"/media/ubuntu/ACER"' exited with non-zero exit status 13:     
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read of MFT, mft=155471 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

After this, I ran through the gamut of things like ntfsprogs and what have you, but that didn't help.

```
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3
Mounting volume... ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read of MFT, mft=155471 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read of MFT, mft=155471 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error
Remount failed: Input/output error
```

And now, my current position. I'm using Testdisk, but I'm sorta lost on how to use it. I chose analyze, deep search, but I have no idea what I'm supposed to be looking for:

```
Disk /dev/sda - 320 GB / 298 GiB - CHS 38913 255 63
Partition Start End Size in sectors
HPFS - NTFS 0 32 33 1529 232 47 24576000 [PQSERVICE]
HPFS - NTFS 1529 232 48 1542 168 34 204800
HPFS - NTFS 1542 168 35 26362 168 46 398733312 [ACER]
HPFS - NTFS 26362 168 47 26420 7 19 921600
HPFS - NTFS 26420 39 52 38913 37 36 200699904 [New Volume]
Structure: Ok. Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
=Primary bootable P=Primary L=Logical E=Extended D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
Enter: to continueroot@ubuntu:~#
NTFS, blocksize=4096, 12 GB / 11 GiB
```

I began to try chkdsk, but it was showing it would take around 60 hours to complete a scan of a 320GB hard drive, which seems like a long time for a hard drive of that size. If push comes to shove, I will try that, but I wanted to see if Ubuntu could help me (like usual). Thanks for reading my tale of woes. Even the smallest amount of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the testdisk manual: It's excellent. It looks like your hdd has NEARLY died: Duplicate it fully using `ddrescue` ASAP and do your data recovery *on the copy*. Or better: Take 2 copies!!!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you - try to use Hiren's boot CD and run mini windows XP
There is a huge amount of tools for partitions and discs. But, maybe, it will mount you HDD automaticly. Here is the link: http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd